# How to create a calculated field using visual studio?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I want to modify the column name of "Created" date. Since this is not possible directly, I want to create a site column and set the "Created" field to this column. This site column can be added to my list too. How can I achieve this ? How to set the Created field's value to Site column ?

EDIT

I'm using SP 2013 & VS 2013.

Comment: Instead of creating a site column, why dont you create a calculated column in your list with value from "Created" column.?

Comment: Can you give me an example? I'm new to sharepoint.

Comment: I can't find the type "Calculated" in visual studio!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the below steps,

1. Navigate to your list and then Create a New column in your list with the required name.
2. Select the type of the column to be "Calculated".
3. In the "Formula" section, select the "Created" column.
4. Select the return datatype.
5. Click "Ok".

Use the below code to add a calculated column programmatically,

```
  using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://serverName/sites/Vijai/"))        
        {           
         using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())    
                {    
                    SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("Custom");        
                if (list != null)         
               {            
                ////Create a calculated field  
                   string calculatedColumn = list.Fields.Add("CalculatedColumn",SPFieldType.Calculated, false);                      
      ////Get the newly created calculated field         
                   SPFieldCalculated calculatedField = list.Fields[calculatedColumn] as SPFieldCalculated;    

                     ////Set the calculated field formula 

                           calculatedField.Formula = "=[Title]";  
                          ////Set the data type returned from this formula  
                          calculatedField.OutputType = SPFieldType.Text;                       
 ////Update the calculated field  
                calculatedField.Update();        
            }          
      }          
  }
```

Use the below code to add the column using Element.xml

```
<Field   Type="Calculated"   DisplayName="Name"  
EnforceUniqueValues="FALSE"   Indexed="FALSE"  
Format="Requiredformat"   LCID="1033"   ResultType="Text"  
ReadOnly="TRUE"   ID="{85353f64-8c8f-4424-ba81-bdc07b9880d6}"  
SourceID="{b9c7c8c2-7106-4219-84f9-b3d7cd0a9760}"   StaticName="Name" 
Name="Name"   ColName="Name"   RowOrdinal="0"   Required="FALSE"  
Percentage="FALSE"   Version="3"> 
<Formula>=[Created]</Formula></Field>
```

Comment: I'm not getting the type "Calculated" in that drop down. I'm creating my list from the visual studio.

Comment: Now, I'm getting the Created field, but unable to get the Modified field!! Any idea ?

Comment: @AnishV Please raise it as a new question, so that it will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Simple...you create your new column, set it to a lookup field then from the properties tab select the "List" and "Field" you want to set it to.

S

Comment: I don't want a column from another list, but from the current lists Created column. How can I do that ?

Comment: Pretty sure you can...should be an easy one to test.

Comment: I have tried that, but Created field is listing as empty.. Not working.. :(